# Clone search fields in jquery/ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm new to this forum and I would like to tell you my problem already.

I need a multiple search field, when I go to enter the first letters I get the results through an AJAX call made on a file in php, the problem is that in the second input field that I have cloned the AJAX scan does not work and I do not suggestions come out.
So how can I go about making multiple search fields work?

I am attaching the code to make you understand better. Thank you all.

```
<div class="cont">
      <input type="text" class="form-control search" id="search">
      <button id="add" onClick="add()">+</button>
  </div>
    
<table class="table table-hover">  
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Firstname</th>
      <th>Lastname</th>
      <th>City</th>
      <th>Salary</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="output">
    
  </tbody>
</table>



function add(){
    $("#search").clone().val("").attr("id", "search").appendTo(".cont");
}   

$("#search").keyup(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'search.php',
        data:{
          name:$(this).val(),
        },
        success:function(data){
           $(".#output").html(data);
        return data;
        }
    });
});
```

I did as you said, but the ajax call in the second input doesn't work, should I call the ajax function to make it work on the new input? How could I do?

**Thanks a lot everyone, I solved it**

Comment: By looking at your code it seems like you have 2 inputs with the same id `search` which is invalid HTML, you can only have 1 element with a particular id. Here's a resource for you to read more: [https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H93.html](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H93.html)

Comment: You can't have multiple buttons with the same ID. By definition, IDs must be unique. Use a class instead to bind your events. See also about delegated events in jQuery using .on(), because you'll need it for dynamically generated elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be identifying a **class** search ..  You are calling an **ID** which is supposed to be *unique*

When cloning remove the ID attribute and use `addClass('search')`

```
$("#search").clone().val("").addClass("search").appendTo(".cont");
```

Then change your selector from: `$("#search")`

To `$(".search")`

in effect calling any element with the **class** search on keyup

**UPDATE**

as @ADyson mentioned in the comment ..  You will need to `bind` the keyup action .. The easiest way to do this is using `on()` ( from the deprecated `.live()` ).  IE:

```
$(document).on('keyup', '.search', function(){
```

FULL SNIPPET:

```js
function add(){
    $("#search").clone().val("").addClass("search").appendTo(".cont");
}   

$(document).on('keyup', '.search', function(){
    alert('Call AJAX');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cont">
      <input type="text" class="form-control search" id="search">
      <button id="add" onClick="add()">+</button>
  </div>
    
<table class="table table-hover">  
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Firstname</th>
      <th>Lastname</th>
      <th>City</th>
      <th>Salary</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="output">
    
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Check out the [API Documentation](https://api.jquery.com/on/) for a full list of events handled through `.on()`

Comment: That's step 1. Step 2 is to implement delegated events so the event handler will bind to elements added to the page after the handler was declared.

Comment: @ADyson -- Quite correct .. I updated my answer to reflect this.